# Beaglebone Black: How to turn pins on/off programatically?

Tags: iot, beagleboneblack, gpio

I have a Beaglebone Black from which I use the some VCC pin. I need to programatically turn on/off VCC pins. 
Say, the VCC pin number is #5, I am looking for some Linux command that will turn that particular pin on/off.

Is it possible via command line? or, there are some other way? is it possible at all?

please help.

Answer (score 0):

What does you mean "VCC pin"?
You can't on/off VDD pins on connector P9 but tou can control GPIO pins (and switch power from VDD pins with an appropriate transistor).
From command line one can control GPIO via sysfs interface.

```
debian@beaglebone:$ cd /sys/class/gpio
debian@beaglebone:/sys/class/gpio$ ls
export   gpio14  gpio26  gpio4   gpio48  gpio60  gpio68      gpiochip64
gpio112  gpio15  gpio27  gpio44  gpio49  gpio61  gpio69      gpiochip96
gpio114  gpio2   gpio3   gpio45  gpio5   gpio65  gpio7       unexport
gpio115  gpio22  gpio30  gpio46  gpio50  gpio66  gpiochip0
gpio116  gpio23  gpio31  gpio47  gpio51  gpio67  gpiochip32
```

You can see here directories for already exported GPIO pins and some additional files, see [GPIO Sysfs Interface for Userspace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt)

For example, I use GPIO49 (P9, pin 23) for LED control:

```
debian@beaglebone:/$ sudo su
root@beaglebone:/# cd /sys/class/gpio/gpio49
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/gpio/gpio49# cat direction 
in
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/gpio/gpio49# echo out >direction 
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/gpio/gpio49# echo 1 >value
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/gpio/gpio49# echo 0 >value
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/gpio/gpio49#
```

So that, you can control GPIO pins manually from command line, from bash script, and from any user-space program using file i/o.